# Somewhy data doesn't add to List

Tags: c#

I have a class named 'feladatok' and I created a List so I can store data from json in it, but for some reason after Adding all elements to the list in a foreach, the List is still empty... Here is my code:

```
public class feladatok
{
    private string event_title;
    private string event_desc;
    private string contact_email;
    private string created_by;

    public feladatok(string title, string desc, string email,string created) {    
        title = event_title;
        desc = event_desc;
        email = contact_email;
        created = created_by; 
    }

    public string getCreatedBy{            
        get { return created_by; }    
        set { this.created_by = value; }    
    }

    public string getTitle {    
        get { return event_title; }    
        set { this.event_title = value; }    
    }    

    public string getDesc {
        get { return event_desc; }    
        set { this.event_desc = value; }    
    }

    public string getEmail {    
        get { return contact_email; }    
        set { this.contact_email = value; }    
    }

}

List<feladatok> lista = new List<feladatok>();

try
{
    JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
    foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
    {
        string title = (string) o.GetValue("event_title");          
        string desc = (string)  o.GetValue("event_desc");
        string email = (string) o.GetValue("contact_email");
        string created_by = (string) o.GetValue("created_by_username");

        //this returns correct items, I checked, so parsing the json is fine

        lista.Add(new feladatok(title, desc, email,created_by));

        //there is some problem with this step, because the items doesn't add to the list...let's say I want to access 'lista[0].getTitle' and it returns nothing. 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I basically did the same programming android application and it works fine..though I store data in an ArrayList there.

Tried to rebuild the project, clean, etc, but nothing.

It might be a simple error in the code I didn't notice so I put it up here, and maybe you can help :)

Comment: Your code adds an item to the list for every `JObject o in a.Children<JObject>()`. If the list ends up empty that means that the collection you're looping through in your `foreach` is empty.

Comment: In your `feladatok` ctor, all your assignments are backwards.

Comment: Have you debugged your application and ensured the loop actually runs?

Comment: It would probably be easier to deserialize it and ignore any properties you dont want.  You may also want to investigate auto implemented properties.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: FYI you shouldn't name properties like that.  Just drop the "get" from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue with the constructor

```
 public feladatok(string title, string desc, string email,string created) {

        title = event_title;
        desc = event_desc;
        email = contact_email;
        created = created_by;


    }
```

It should be other way around

```
 public feladatok(string title, string desc, string email,string created) {

        event_title = title;
        event_desc = desc;
        contact_email = email;
        created_by = created;


    }
```

As you have said lista[0].getTitle returns nothing, it means items have been added to list but values are not assigned.

Comment: Actually the fields will be `null`, not `string.Empty`.

Comment: Oh well...it really was a simple problem...Sorry for being stupid, only started to learn programming in September. It works now! yaay, but why does it matter which way I do it?

Comment: @Limweire because the right side is assigned to the left side.  Your code assigns the default values of the fields to the arguments while the correct code assigns the arguments to the fields.

Comment: Ah I understand now!